# Can't start terminal after some problems with python installation

Tags: command-line, apt, gnome, python, gnome-terminal

I am using GNOME, so its terminal depends on python.
I messed it up, so now I can't run terminal (but I can use xterm).

I changed links to python a bit, so now python's links works fine (hope so):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
```

And update-alternatives:

```
me@me:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.7   1         manual mode


me@me:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There is 1 choice for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.7   1         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.7   1         manual mode
```

But still, I can't run my terminal and even pip3:

```
me@me:~$ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

Is there any way to fix it? maybe just delete every python version and pip version and install it again? Or something else?

Comment: what did you mess up?